# Access wpdb with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, wordpress

I'm starting with AngularJS and I want to use it in my WordPress site.

I'm trying to print a table with the data of a table in my WordPress database but I can't access to the WordPress functions and variables.

This following is some of my code.

page-demo.php

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Demo
 */

get_header(); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript"
    src="<?php echo get_option('siteurl')?>/wp-content/themes/theme1200/js/app.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript"
    src="<?php echo get_option('siteurl')?>/wp-content/themes/theme1200/js/smart-table.min.js"></script>


<meta name="description"
    content="Basic AngularJS example of data binding" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body >
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <h3>Basic Smart-Table Starter</h3>
        <table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>first name</th>
                  <th>last name</th>
                  <th>birth date</th>
                <th>balance</th>
                <th>email</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
                <td>{{row.NOMBRE}}</td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>

<?php 
get_footer(); 
?>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [ 'smart-table' ]).controller('mainCtrl',
        function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('../wp-content/themes/theme1200/model/model.php').
            success(function(data) {
                $scope.rowCollection = data;            
            })      
        });
```

model.php

```
<?php 

global $wpdb;

//$query = "SELECT * FROM JUGADOR";
//$resultado = $wpdb->get_results($query);

$sql = "SELECT APELLIDOS, NOMBRE, HANDICAP FROM JUGADOR ORDER BY APELLIDOS";
$res = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sql));

$result = $res->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
# JSON-encode the response
$json = json_encode( $result );
echo $json;

?>
```

But I'm having an error when it execute the following line.

```
$res = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sql));
```

I think that this file can't access to wordpress functions and variables.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: study some tutorials for using ajax in wordprss. It exposes a whole api you can easily extend

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in thinking that your script does not have access to Wordpress functions and variables. Running a php script directly like that will mean Wordpress is not set up.

A better approach is to hook in to Wordpress and set up urls which will return the data you want from there, for Angular to use. There are a couple of different ways you can go about this.

There is a [Wordpress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/) which can be used with the likes of Angular. It allows you to get data very easily, but the focus is on core Wordpress data not a custom databse. But it's worth a look.

Another is to create your own endpoint, which will allow you to return whatever you want from a given url. [Here is an article](http://coderrr.com/create-an-api-endpoint-in-wordpress/) looking at that approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is always best to use the ajax functions built into wordpress.

[Setting up ajax. I have used it outside of plugins. It works the same.](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Here is a rough version of the code

This adds code to `footer.php`. You could also enqueue your script in a separate js file (highly recommended). In either case you want to read the `ajaxurl`

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_action_javascript' ); // Write our JS below here

function my_action_javascript() { ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
    angular.module('myApp', [ 'smart-table' ]).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get(ajaxurl).
            success(function(data) {
                $scope.rowCollection = data;
            })
        });
    </script> <?php
}
```

Then in your `functions.php` add the following.

```
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback() {

    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "SELECT APELLIDOS, NOMBRE, HANDICAP FROM JUGADOR ORDER BY APELLIDOS";
    $res = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sql));

    $result = $res->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    # JSON-encode the response
    $json = json_encode( $result );
    echo $json;

}
```

That should get you most of the way there. Check the link and it should help you tweak it.